# Capture a response from jquery submitForm

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, yii

I have the following code that I use with Yii framework to delete one register. 
This code is automatic generated and I'd like to capture if it was submited when the dialog open. If the ajax is complete I'll save in my user log.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery('body').on('click','#yt0', function(){
        if (confirm('Want to delete it?')) {
            jQuery.yii.submitForm(this,'/yiiProject/index.php?r=project/delete&id=168',{});
            return false;
        } 
        else 
            return false;
    });

    jQuery('body').tooltip({'selector':'a[rel=tooltip]'});
    jQuery('body').popover({'selector':'a[rel=popover]'});
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, why not write to the log in the server side code though?

Comment: Because I'll need to write in all classes and if I do something globally, I'll just write one time. Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: Not familiar with Yii but from knowing jQuery you can't just "tap" into those events from external code. Server side is really the preferred way, sure you can't do that?

Comment: I understand what you say. Anyway my problem is how can I detect if the ajax delete request have success. Then I'll get the result (true or false) and pass to server side to save in the log.

Comment: Most I can offer is detecting when user click OK in the confirm dialog, see my answer.

Comment: Thats madness. Just use ajaxlink, and call your custom js function on success. Write to log on server side. Return success/failed from your controller (where your ajax call performed). In success ajax call - your success message or whatever you want to make.

Answer (score 1):

Most you can do as far as I can see is override the `confirm` method and handle the case when user click OK:

```
var originalConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function(msg) {
    if (originalConfirm(msg)) {
        //log...
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

You can also override Yii auto generated code completely by sumbitting the AJAX yourself then always returning false:

```
if (originalConfirm(msg)) {
    $.post("/yiiProject/index.php?r=project/delete&id=168", function() {
        //success, write to log...
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think it will solve my problem. Do you know how can I get the ajax link submited? For example in this case: "/yiiProject/index.php?r=project/delete&id=168"

Comment: I think override the Yii code is not the best solution, because if I do it I have to override in all classes. With the first block of code I can dettect when it was confirmed, If i can get the link that I sent my problem will be solved. I'm not sure but if I can get the window submit link, it will be done.

Comment: @Renan if you add `alert($("#yt0").attr("action"));` to the code I gave, what you see?

Comment: It doesn't work. The element #yt0 don't have associated to him that he has a jquery method. When I click on the #yt0, the jquery do the job and not the element <a href="#" id="yt0">Delete</a>

Comment: @Renan hmm... so where is the 168 is taken from? Can you put it in the DOM somewhere?

Comment: sorry I don't undertand.

Comment: OK, think it got too complicated - the answer to "can I get the link that I sent?" is most likely "no", sorry.

Comment: When I click ok, the jquery triggered will be sent. Maybe I can get the server side link submited too, do you have some suggestion about it?

Comment: @Renan no, like I said in the beginning you can't "tap" into those things.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the global ajax events:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    if ( settings.url == "ajax/test.html" ) {
        $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSuccess handler. The ajax response was: " +
        xhr.responseText );
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but jQuery code that I wrote is auto generated.
I'd like just to get the url when the ajax call was submited.

Comment: The global events are fired on each AJAX request.